# Show/Hide Header

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a header with the following structure:

```
 <header>
    <div class="container-fluid login-div">
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-10"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid register-div">
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-10"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid nav-header middle">
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 line-right"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt=" LOGO" id="img_logo"> </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 line-right"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

When the page loads, `login-div` and `register-div` are hidden. When a user clicks on a certain button, these div's show (well, depending on which button is clicked). The issue I'm having is that I can't get the div to show all content.

I've created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7wuzzm09/), so you can check it out.

Now just before everyone tells me to set a height, I can't because I don't know what the height will be. Depending on what the user selects, the height of the content will change.

Comment: Actually what you want? you like to show `register-div` on login click?

Comment: whts your problem sir?

Comment: Did you need something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/7wuzzm09/2/ ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/39axfct7/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/schwiegler/7wuzzm09/1/ this is an updated version of your fiddle.

I added the following to your registration class `height:100%;` let me know if it is working to your liking and up-vote and select as answer if I helped.

Comment: This is better than my answer. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically update the `.register-div` height. See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7wuzzm09/7/.

Note, I haven't accounted the padding, you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS:

Instead of specifying `height:0px` and `overflow:hidden` specify `display: none;` for login and register div.

In their respective `.active` classes make it `display: block;`

```
.login-div,
.register-div {
    z-index:1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background:#dbdfe2;
    color:#515151;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}

.login-div.active {
    padding:37px;
    display: block;
}

.register-div.active {
    padding:15px;
    display: block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7wuzzm09/6/)**